# How to setup vim open file request will direct to already opened file in earlier terminal?

Tags: vim, terminal, editor, vi, nautilus

I have opened a file by double click on file icon in a file browser (let's say from nautilus). The file will open in vim running on a terminal (let's say in gnome terminal). Let's say I will try to open the same file again by double click on file icon in the file browser again. This time the vim opened in terminal will give you the annoying message to open file in readonly, etc... mode.

I need a method to direct to view the older gnome terminal when the file is already open in it. Other gui based editors (like gedit) got this options. If there is no such options available then I am on to use gvim is it has such feature.

Comment: I doubt that there is such an option in Vim, as it is no GUI-based editor.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has client-server capabilities which can be used for this purpose. By default, when you open a `gvim` window, a server is started. The server name will be in the title bar, and by default the first one is `GVIM`, the second is `GVIM2`, the next is `GVIM3`, and so on.

It's possible to open a file in the same window by invoking `vim` or `gvim` with the `--remote` or `--remote-silent` options (the latter prints no error if the server is missing). You can specify a different server other than the first one by using `--servername SERVER`.

If your goal is to always only use one Vim session, no matter how you invoke the program, then you can always use `gvim` and set GNOME to open files with `gvim --remote-silent`, and also set that in your shell configuration with `export EDITOR="gvim --remote-silent"`. Then you will always open in a single window, no matter what you're doing.

If you want only files in the GUI to open in one window and continue to use command-line Vim for other tasks, then leave your shell configuration pointing to `vim` and set GNOME to open files with `gvim --remote-silent`, so that it will open all the files from the GUI in `gvim` and leave your other sessions alone.